# JSON does not allow non-finite numbers

Tags: java, grails

What are the cause and some example this can occur?

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.exceptions.ConverterException: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONException: JSON does not allow non-finite numbers
```

Comment: My guess is you have a value which is NaN or infinite and your JSON generator doesn't know how to handle this.

Comment: what you mean infinite?

Comment: @fsi, Java floating point (a.k.a., IEEE floating point) handles certain overflow-like or undefined operations by returning certain distinguished values.  E.g., sqrt(-1) ==> NaN (i.e., Not a Number).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Exception_handling

Comment: I meant positive or negative infinity.